# Listbox.Sorted = True - No Longer part of VBA?

Tags: vba, sorting

I have been looking for a simple way to order values in a list box in VBA and I see a lot of references using `listbox.sorted = true`.  However, I can't replicate that code.  Below is an image I took from my code. Am I completely missing something? I can't find the `.sorted` option for a listbox anywhere.  Is this function no longer an option?

[image]

Comment: I have found numerous example of people using this.  Even found the documentation here... [Click Me](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's a part of the .NET framework (see [System.Windows.Forms.Listbox.Sorted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.sorted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)), and it's not available in VBA as far as I know.